# How to sum columns in SPSS Syntax

Tags: syntax, spss

I have a table in SPSS that contains multiple columns, like this:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|        | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Total |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data 1 |    10 |     1 |    30 |    41 |
| Data 2 |     4 |    10 |    10 |    24 |
| Data 3 |     3 |    40 |     1 |    44 |
| Data 4 |    10 |     5 |     3 |    18 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to add a row at the bottom that calculates the total of each column. in the end, it would look something like this:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|        | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Total |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data 1 |    10 |     1 |    30 |    41 |
| Data 2 |     4 |    10 |    10 |    24 |
| Data 3 |     3 |    40 |     1 |    44 |
| Data 4 |    10 |     5 |     3 |    18 |
| TOTAL  |    27 |    56 |    44 |   127 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Does anyone know what I would have to add to my current code to achieve this?

EDIT: Here is my current code:

```
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF Remove = 0.
CTABLES 
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=TBI1 ME1 BFCE1 CFCE1 RTWPM1 VPA1 NPS1 NPA1 PROV 
    DISPLAY=LABEL
  /TABLE TBI1 [C] + ME1 [C] + BFCE1 [C] + CFCE1 [C] + RTWPM1 [C] + VPA1 [C] + NPS1 [C] + NPA1 [C] BY PROV [C]
  [COUNT F40.0, ROWPCT.COUNT PCT40.1]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=TBI1 ME1 BFCE1 CFCE1 RTWPM1 VPA1 NPS1 NPA1 [1.00] EMPTY=INCLUDE
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=PROV ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE TOTAL=YES 
  /TITLES TITLE='Brain Injury' CAPTION='Type of assessment and volume of each service by provider.'.
```

Comment: (1) Are you trying to add a line to you data, or to get the output to display such a table? (2) You mentioned your "current code" - please post the code or relevant part of it so it's possible to understand how the data was generated and what needs to be added.

Comment: Hey Eli, to answer your first question, I am indeed trying to add a line to the data, as I already have the rest of the table generated. To the second question, I will update the question to include the current code I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get output like this from the CROSSTABS procedure (Analyze > Descriptive Statistics > Crosstabs)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option you may want to try.
Create two new variables in syntax window.

```
COMPUTE ALL_TAB_COL = 1.
COMPUTE ALL_TAB_ROW = 1.
EXECUTE.

VARIABLE LABELS ALL_TAB_COL 'All Cols'
/ALL_TAB_ROW 'All Rows'.
```

Go to Main Menu Analyze > Tables > Custom Tables
From Variable List
Drag `ALL_TAB_COL` to Column Area
Drag `ALL_TAB_ROW` to Row Area (if needed)

Thereafter you can drag other column to appear after `ALL_TAB_COL`;
and row variables to appear below  `ALL_TAB_ROW`.

In Summary statistics submenu if you choose `Count`, the `ALL_TAB_COL` shows, Column Sum of all Counts against the `ALL_TAB_ROW` and further break ups by other variables.